# How to use a character vector of column names in the formula argument of dcast (reshape2)

Tags: r, reshape2

Say I have a dataframe `df` with dozens of identifying variables (in columns) and only a few measured variables (also in columns).

To avoid repetitively typing all the variables for each argument, I assign the names of the identifying and measured `df` columns to `df_id` and `df_measured`, respectively. It's easy enough to input these vectors to shorten the argument inputs for `melt`...

```
df.m  <- melt(df, id.vars = df_id, measure.vars = df_measured)
```

... but I'm at a loss for how to enter the  `formula =` argument in `dcast` using the same method to specify my id variables since it requires that the input point to numeric positions of the columns.

Do I have to make a vector of numeric positions similar to `df_id` and risk broken functionality of my program if my input columns change in order, or can I refer to them by name and somehow still get that to work in the `formula =` argument? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean that "it requires that the input point to numeric positions"? Can you provide a sample of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It's easy to convert a vector of characters to a formula, but I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `as.formula` to construct a formula.

Here's an example:

```
library(reshape2)
## Example from `melt.data.frame`
names(airquality) <- tolower(names(airquality))
df_id <- c("month", "day")
aq <- melt(airquality, id = df_id)

## Constructing the formula
f <- as.formula(paste(paste(df_id, collapse = " + "), "~ variable"))

## Applying it....
dcast(aq, f, value.var = "value", fun.aggregate = mean)
```

Comment: I'm still surprised that in 3 years that's the most elegant solution...

Comment: See below! Using the Tidyverse *glue()* function, one can avoid the proliferation of commas and quotes that comes with *paste()* .

Comment: for me it is working without `as.formula()` with just something like `f <- paste(my.col, "~ variable")`

Answer (score 0):

The function *glue()* , exported from the Tidyverse package [*glue*](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/10/glue-1.2.0/) , makes the formula easier to build than with *paste()* . Here's what *glue()* does:

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
glue( "{a} + {b} = {a+b}." )
```

returns the string

```
1 + 2 = 3.
```

So *glue()* takes its argument verbatim, but substitutes names and other expressions in curly brackets. See the link above for the full spec: *glue()* has other arguments, including more strings, an argument that gives the environment in which to look up variables, and two arguments that change the curly brackets to other delimiters. As far as *dcast()* is concerned, it avoids the extra quotes and commas that you have to use with *paste()* . Here's an example, using your table:

```
install.packages( "glue" )
library( glue )

library( data.table ) 

dt <- data.table( c1 = c( 1  , 1  , 1  , 2   , 2   , 2    )    
                , c2 = c( "A", "B", "C", "A1", "B1", "C1" )
                , c3 = c( 1  , 2  , 3  , 1   , 2   , 3    )
                )

f1 <- function( d, col_name1, col_name2, col_name3 ) {
  dcast( d, glue( "{col_name1} ~ {col_name3}" ), value.var = col_name2 )
}

f1( dt, "c1", "c2", "c3" )
```

And here's its output (on R 3.6.3):

```
> f1( dt, "c1", "c2", "c3" )
   c1  1  2  3
1:  1  A  B  C
2:  2 A1 B1 C1
```

Answer (score 0):

For people using base R, `sprintf()` is fine compared to `glue::glue()`:

```
vars_to_use <- c("Petal.Length", "Sepal.Length")

as.formula(sprintf("Species ~ %s", 
                   paste(vars_to_use, collapse = " + ")))

## Species ~ Petal.Length + Sepal.Length
```

As a bonus, if you can ever use `sprintf()` instead of using `paste()` at all, you'll get a performance improvement since it's implemented in C.